# `runhaskell` can't see packages if the arguments are passed in the form of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, quotes, runhaskell

Whenever I pass explicit parameters to `runhaskell` command using a variable, in order to make a specific package visible, for example:

```hs
#!/bin/bash
args="'-package pandoc'"

runhaskell --ghc-arg="$args"<<EOF

import Text.Pandoc

main :: IO ()
main = print $ "Hello World"
EOF
```

I get the error:

> : error: Can't find '-package pandoc'
> *** Exception: ExitFailure 1

However, if I enter the contents of that variable explicitly:

```hs
#!/bin/bash

runhaskell --ghc-arg='-package pandoc'<<EOF

import Text.Pandoc

main :: IO ()
main = print $ "Hello World"
EOF
```

The script works as expected. Does someone know why is this the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing this escaped a second time. You should work with:

```
#!/bin/bash
args="-package pandoc"  # no quotations in the string

runhaskell --ghc-arg="$args"<<EOF

import Text.Pandoc

main :: IO ()
main = print $ "Hello World"
EOF
```

By using `"$args"` it is already clear that you use this as a single parameter, but if you use single quotes *inside* the string, these will be passed as *content* of the parameter. In other words you will call `ghc-arg` with `'-package pandoc'` as *content* of the first argument, where the single quotes are thus not interpreted by the shell, but given to the `runhaskell` executable. Since this does *not* start with a hyphen (`-`) likely the interpreter assumes it is the name of the file to run and not a flag, and thus looks for a file with that name in the working directory.

You can also pass multiple parameters, without quotes for `$args`:

```
#!/bin/bash
args="-package=pandoc -package=pandoc-types"  # no quotations in the string

runhaskell -- $args <<EOF

import Text.Pandoc

main :: IO ()
main = print $ "Hello World"
EOF
```

The `echo` command can for example show the *content* of the parameter:

```
$ echo 'foo'
foo
$ echo '"foo"'
"foo"
$ echo "foo"
foo
$ echo "'foo'"
'foo'
```

The "outer" quotes (whether `'` or `"`) are thus interpreted by the shell, but the inner quotes (if present) are passed as parameter value.

Comment: Thank you so much ! +1 What happens if I must use more than one package ? I gave the minimal reproducible example, but in general I use more than one.

Comment: `args="-package pandoc -package pandoc-types"` gives

Comment: Can't parse package flag: pandoc -package pandoc-types

Comment: @F.Zer: it takes a single arg, so I think `--ghc-arg="-package p1" --ghc-arg="-package p2"`?

Comment: @F.Zer: but you don't need the `--ghc-arg` in the first place I think, you can use `runhaskell -- -package p1 -package p2` I think?

Comment: Thank you. Just tried: `runhaskell -- "$args"` where `args="'-package pandoc' '-package pandoc-types'"` and I get: `target ‘'-package pandoc' '-package pandoc-types'’ is not a module name or a source file`

Comment: @F.Zer: does the edit work?